# Filtering ACTION_SEND sharing options

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using the following code to share information from my application.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "share Content" );
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "share subject" );
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share Place via"));
```

The above code displays some options through which i can share, What i would like to achieve is somehow go through the options and omit some of them.

For Example , in my case, if Facebook app is present on the device, the above code displays it as one of the options. As i already have Facebook android sdk integrated in my application. I want to remove the Facebook option from the sharing options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have a look at the `PackageManager` [`queryIntentActivities (Intent intent, int flags)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) methods. This will give you a list of `Activities` matching your `Intent`and then you can maybe remove some of them, and present a custom `Dialog` to the user, where you show just the desired `Activities`. And after the user chooses an `Activity` you'll have to explicitly start that `Activity`.